# Eclipse Maven XStream - Unable to make field accessible - module does not "opens modele" to module xstream

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xstream

I can not make XStream working and I do not know why. I am in a Maven projet, JRE-11, MVC model, XStream 1.4.18. I am french btw. Thanks in advance.
I just put an exemple with the UE class, but I want to do this with "Classe" and "Creneau".
I tried "xstream.alias", but did not work.

[image]

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Archi</groupId>
  <artifactId>Archi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.18</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Archi.java

```
package controlleur;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

import modele.*;
import vue.*;

public class Archi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Classe classe = new Classe("IATIC5", 2020, 2021);
        UE ue = new UE("ARC", "EU-Archi");
        Creneau creneau = new Creneau(9, 11, 2021, 20, 22);
        
        Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();
        
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        String xml = xstream.toXML(ue);
        System.out.println(xml);
        
        Controlleur controlleur = new Controlleur(classe, ue, creneau, fenetre);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package controlleur;

import modele.*;
import vue.*;

public class Controlleur {  
    public Controlleur(Classe classe, UE ue, Creneau creneau, Fenetre fenetre) {
        fenetre.affiche(classe, ue, creneau);
    }
}
```

UE.java

```
package modele;

import java.util.UUID;

public class UE {
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), sigle, nomination;

    public UE(String sigle, String nomination) {
        this.sigle = sigle;
        this.nomination = nomination;
    }

    //All getter, setter and toString
}
```

error text

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No converter available
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No converter available
type                : modele.UE
converter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
message[1]          : Unable to make field private java.lang.String modele.UE.id accessible: module archi does not "opens modele" to module xstream
-------------------------------
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:88)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$1.lookupConverterForType(XStream.java:472)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:48)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1243)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1232)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1205)
    at xstream@1.4.18/com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1192)
    at archi/controlleur.Archi.main(Archi.java:17)
```

Comment: Does deleting your `module-info.java` file fix your issue? Or if you want to keep it to enable the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), does `module-info.java` contain the line `exports modele;`?

Comment: @howgler
module-info.java only have:
module archi {
         requires xstrem;
}

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found out what was wrong in my project.

I was developing a JavaFX with data persistence in XML with XStream. When attempting to read the file, I had the same issue.

In order to fix it, I did the following:

- Save the models/javabeans on a directory.

```
MODULE/javabeans/
  PeopleXML.java
  PersonXML.java
```

- Modify the module to allow XStream to use these classes (`module-info.java`)

```
module MODULE {
    ...
    requires xstream;

    ...
    opens MODULE.javabeans to xstream;
    exports MODULE.javabeans;
}
```

- Implement the code normally.

```java
XStream xstream = new XStream();

xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
xstream.addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
xstream.addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);

xstream.allowTypes(new Class[]{PersonXML.class, PeopleXML.class});

xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
    "MODULE.javabeans.**"
});

xstream.alias("people", PeopleXML.class);
xstream.alias("person", PersonXML.class);

xstream.addImplicitCollection(PeopleXML.class, "lstPeople"); // Collection name

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFilename);
        return (PeopleXML) xstream.fromXML(fis);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new InvalidDataException("File not found: " + xmlFilename);
}
```

**Note:** `MODULE` is the module you are working on.